# Kong: limit concurrent requests per consumer

Tags: lua, kong, kong-plugin

I'm trying to find information on how to allow a consumer to have only X(10) concurrent open connections in Kong with no luck. Is it even possible? If not, would it be possible to do it with custom plugin and how hard would it be to implement such plugin?
Thanks.